# Безопасность через websocket

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, golang, websocket

В интернете много статей про websocket, какой он быстрый и замечательный, но нигде не нашёл  информации как сделать соединение безопасным.

Допустим имеем клиента(браузер), веб-сервер(`php`) и WS сервер(`ratchet | golang | node.js`). Как между ними тремя организовать взаимодействие, в самом простом варианте, чтобы только аутентифицированные пользователи(на веб-сервере) имели доступ к WS серверу?
Мысли вслух):

- -генерировать на веб-сервере уникальный стойкий id
- -передать его клиенту
- -от клиента get параметром(это плохо? если да то как исправить)на WS
- -с WS сервера на веб-сервер для проверки существования такого id?

Возможно порядок неправельный, подскажите правильный пожалуйста. В общем буду рад выслушать любое замечание и предложение по этому поводу.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78060/discussion-on-question-by-----websocket).